# Reliable method to determine system language in OS X

Tags: osx, i18n

I was hoping to do something like

```
defaults read -g AppleLanguages | awk -F, '/[^(]/{print $1;exit}'
```

but if only one language is listed in "Preferred Languages", then `defaults read -g AppleLanguages` returns an error:

> The domain/default pair of (kCFPreferencesAnyApplication, AppleLanguages) does not exist

It works fine if multiple languages are listed.
Does anyone have a reliable way of determining the language selected for a given user in OS X?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but I suggest you ask on http://apple.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: [Reposted on Apple.SE](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/169789/determining-preferred-language-in-os-x-via-cli). @jayhendren [Please do not suggest cross-posting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu). This is one rare case where the question is genuinely on-topic on both sites, but **if you must ask in two different places, then at least link your questions to each other**. Otherwise, you're making people answer twice, which is rude.

Comment: What should I do instead, then? I don't see an option to "flag for migration".